# STL Container with generic templated base type, accepting derived types

Tags: c++, templates, generics, unordered-map, derived

I would like to create a map with an EventHandler of a Base type but insert into that map several derived EventHandlers like such:

```
std::unordered_map<int, EventHandler<Base>*> maap;
EventHandler<Derived>* e1 = new EventHandler<Derived>();
maap.emplace(std::make_pair(1, e1));
```

This is possible with pointers of simple objects but here, EventHandler<> is a templated object so the compiler is fussing about converting. 
It would be nice if I could do something like

```
template <class T>
std::unordered_map<int, EventHandler<T>> maap;
```

But that doesn't work either... Any ideas?

Comment: The only option that comes into my mind is to wirte a variant class that can hold all your EventHandler types and use a map to this. E.g. you could use boost variant for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sort of came up with a solution. I made an empty abstract class IEventHandler and inherited EventHandler from that class. Then I make a map of IEventHandler* and it seems to work fine for now. It can have EventHandler of any type added. I need to now find a way to make sure IEventHandler is only inherited by EventHandler and that it is only of the proper T type.

2 little updates:
I used a static_cast to be able to call the EventHandlers method, and because it is casting to a pointer there is no extra copy constructor called ^_^
I restricted who can derived from IEventHandler by giving it a private destructor and friending EventHandler

Comment: `I need to now find a way to make sure IEventHandler is only inherited by EventHandler` why impose such restriction?

Comment: Control over intended use. But I realized this is not a good solution after all. I still need IEventHandler to have a function which takes a <T> type parameter, that leads to my old problem again. I'll post an update if I figure something out.

Comment: I ended up just doing a static_cast<> to turn the IEventHandler to EventHandler<T>. I feel so dirty.

Comment: Your solution in the answer was good. Then you just inherit from base class like this: `template <typename T> class HandlerOne : public IEventHandler` and have intended behaviour.